# android studio:Unable to create media player

Tags: android

> Why do i get this error? Please help!
>
> 10-17 09:34:13.217 17220-20262/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer
> E/MediaPlayer: Unable to create media player

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button b_play;

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
String stream="https://www.internet-radio.com/station/danceradioukchatbox/";

boolean prepared = false;
boolean started = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b_play =(Button) findViewById(R.id.b_play);
    b_play.setEnabled(false);
    b_play.setText("LOADING");

    mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    new PlayerTask().execute(stream);

    b_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (started){
                started = false;
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                b_play.setText("PLAY");
            } else {
                started = true;
                mediaPlayer.start();
                b_play.setText("PAUSE");
            }
        }
    });
}

class PlayerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            prepared = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return prepared;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        b_play.setEnabled(true);
        b_play.setText("PLAY");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (started){
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (started){
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (prepared){
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
} }





> 0-17 10:17:35.383 32413-32413/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer
    > E/MediaPlayer: pause called in state 0
    >     10-17 10:17:135.413 32413-19389/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer I/MediaPlayer: This
    > is not a sprint project
    >     10-17 10:17:35.423 32413-19389/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer E/MediaPlayer: Unable
    > to create media player
    >     10-17 10:17:35.423 32413-19389/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer W/System.err:
    > java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
    >     10-17 10:17:35.423 32413-19389/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer W/System.err:     at
    > android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
    >     10-17 10:17:35.423 32413-19389/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer W/System.err:     at
    > android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1248)
    >     10-17 10:17:35.433 32413-19389/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer W/System.err:     at
    > android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1180)
    >     10-17 10:17:35.433 32413-19389/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer W/System.err:     at
    > com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer.MainActivity$PlayerTask$override.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:64)
    >     10-17 10:17:35.433 32413-19389/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer W/System.err:     at
    > com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer.MainActivity$PlayerTask$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
    >     10-17 10:17:35.433 32413-19389/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer W/System.err:     at
    > com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer.MainActivity$PlayerTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:0)
    >     10-17 10:17:35.433 32413-19389/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer W/System.err:     at
    > com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer.MainActivity$PlayerTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:57)
    >     10-17 10:17:35.433 32413-19389/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer W/System.err:     at
    > android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    >     10-17 10:17:35.433 32413-19389/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer W/System.err:     at
    > java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    >     10-17 10:17:35.433 32413-19389/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer W/System.err:     at
    > android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    >     10-17 10:17:35.433 32413-19389/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer W/System.err:     at
    > java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    >     10-17 10:17:35.433 32413-19389/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer W/System.err:     at
    > java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    >     10-17 10:17:35.433 32413-19389/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer W/System.err:     at
    > java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
    >     10-17 10:17:38.643 32413-32413/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer D/[MediaPluginDLNA]:
    > [getIsRegionSupported] sRegionCode: 6
    >     10-17 10:17:38.643 32413-32413/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer D/[MediaPluginDLNA]:
    > not in Mirror mode
    >     10-17 10:17:38.643 32413-32413/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer D/MediaPlayer:
    > doStart() in
    >     10-17 10:17:38.643 32413-32413/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer D/MediaPlayer:
    > Htc_getIntParameter get error: -38
    >     10-17 10:17:38.643 32413-32413/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer E/MediaPlayer: start
    > called in state 1
    >     10-17 10:17:38.643 32413-32413/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer E/MediaPlayer: error
    > (-38, 0)
    >     10-17 10:17:38.643 32413-32413/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer D/MediaPlayer:
    > Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 100
    >     10-17 10:17:38.643 32413-32413/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer E/MediaPlayer: Error
    > (-38,0)
    >     10-17 10:17:40.133 32413-32413/com.example.e19adm.onlineradioplayer E/MediaPlayer: pause
    > called in state 0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to create media player (using url)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832921/unable-to-create-media-player-using-url)

Comment: You really should add more of the logcat instead of only the top line

Comment: it seem your link is wrong and does not include an audio file such as:  https://..../fileName.mp3

Comment: This is a website, not the direct audio stream.  https://www.internet-radio.com/station/danceradioukchatbox/

Comment: @BananaHero3 , try it : http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Canon.mp3

Comment: @cricket_007 I tried http://www.virginmegastore.me/Library/Music/CD_001214/Tracks/Track1.mp3/ but still does not work...

Comment: @Saeid Still nothing... I guess it's something with the code...

Comment: try stream , play and execute your code in onCreate() method without  AsyncTask and flag , just play it simply with this link stephaniequinn.com/Music/Canon.mp3 , if you have problem still , may your connection have problem or etc...

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding the permission to access `INTERNET` to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: @BananaHero3 - Please add more lines of the `LogCat` to your question.

Comment: i just did please take a look

Comment: @BananaHero3 - Paste the entire `LogCat` from tip to toe!

Comment: Probably should have been a comment before an answer

Comment: Internet permission is one of the reasons for the above mentioned issue